# How to pass 2 property arguments in one command using terminal

Tags: java, jenkins, command-line, terminal

I want to run my tests by using one command and passing two arguments like `-Pintegration` and `-Pfunction`. How can i pass 2 arguments property in one command using terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to take parameters in you would make your main class look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Arg1 : "+ args[0] + " Arg 2: " + args[1]);
}
```

Then when you run your program, you put in your 2 parameters, say `Pintegration` and `Pfunction`, by doing `java yourclass -Pintegration -Pfunction` and your output would be:

```
Arg1 : Pintegration Arg 2: Pfunction
```

To take  arguments in from the command line you use the `args` variable. They will be ordered according to the order you take the in.